# IOS 7 - Search Display Controller in TableView White Scrollview Background - Cannot change background color

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app I'm using dark table and cells. I've set everything to black in my storyboard, and when it all works perfect until I add a Search Display Controller.  The search box itself is the desired color, but when I pull down, I see a scroll view that is white.  I cannot find anywhere in the storyboard settings to change that background color.   I've checked several places to include searching this site in depth.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've gone as far as calling this helper I found on stackoverflow from viewDidLoad and programmatically setting all backgrounds to black. It still shows up as white. I've tried this for the self.view  self.tableView self.searchDisplayController  and still no dice.

```
- (void)listSubviewsOfView:(UIView *)view {

    // Get the subviews of the view
    NSArray *subviews = [view subviews];

    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    for (UIView *subview in subviews)
    {

        [subview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

        NSLog(@"%@, %@", [subview class], subview.backgroundColor);

        [self listSubviewsOfView:subview];

    }
}
```

Comment: My profile pic shows you what I mean.... I'm too new to post pics yet.

Comment: You need to set the background colour of the table view to clear and the view controller (it's view) to the background colour you want. Or set both to the background colour you want, same result either way. You'll find settings for background colour under 'Table view' and 'View'.

Comment: Hi sooper.  I tried exactly as you have said and the scroll view that appears before searching when pulling down on the table is still white.  I'm searching through the view structure now (in code) to see if I can find which view it is.

Comment: You may have better luck doing this programatically.

Comment: Totally agree if I can find that scrollview that's being added to the top of the tableview!!  This is like a phantom view I'm trying to chase down for weeks now.

Answer (score 4):

Accidentally I found a solution to this problem. If you set the backgroundView property of the table view to anything, for example:

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

the white background disappears and backgroundColor is visible as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Use this method .. it will call when you start searching..

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor anyColor];
}
```

Comment: Close, but not the one. The method you gave happens when you start typing in the search field.  This particular view happens before you search and if you just pull down on the table view.  It's only there when the search results controller is attached. When I remove search results controller I get a black background.  Thanks for the answer though! I'll read up on those methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that while searching, another table view is loaded by the searchDisplayController.

So you may need to set the backgroundColor of the searchResultsTableView, like this:

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]]; //Purple couldn't be a good choice :)
```